# Extract only alphabetic characters from VARCHAR column

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g, oracle9i

I have a column of type `VARCHAR2` which has text like `'12-MAR-2014,,1234,DATA,VALUE,12/03/14,,124,End'`. And I need the output to be, `'%DATA%VALUE%End%'`. i.e. the text to be delimited by comma `','`. Only alphabets need to be selected leaving out the date or numeric or special characters. Something like,

```
select some_function('12-MAR-2014,,1234,DATA,VALUE,12/03/14,,124,End') as output from dual;

OUTPUT
---------
%DATA%VALUE%End%
```

**EDIT:**

Another added requirement where alphanumeric values need to be retained:

```
select some_function('12-MAR-2014,,1234,DATA65,VALUE,12/03/14,,124,End') as output from dual;

OUTPUT
---------
%DATA65%VALUE%End%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may help you:

```
select regexp_replace('12-MAR-2014,,1234,DATA,VALUE,12/03/14,,124,End','[[0-9]{2}-(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)-[0-9]{4}]*|[^a-zA-Z]+|$','%') from dual
```

Comment: Works perfectly. But I tried to make this work for alphanumeric characters like select regexp_replace('12-MAR-2014,,1234,DATA65,VALUE,12/03/14,,124,End','[[0-9]{2}-(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)-[0-9]{4}]*|[^[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*]|$','%') from dual. But doesn't seem to work. I know I'm missing something very obvious. What should be changed to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regexp_replace()`.  I think the expression is something like this:

```
select regexp_replace(col, '([^a-zA-Z]+)', '%')
```

Unfortunately, I cannot test this right now (and SQL Fiddle is down).

Comment: Unfortunately will not work - "MAR" corresponds to pattern but should not be in results. :(